# iOS IAP for limited purchase count of an item. Consumable or not?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app

If we provide a limited purchasable item to a user, ie 'you can purchase the limited jewel only 3 times', which one is more Apple IAP guideline friendly?

1. register one **Consumable** item ('limited jewel': $0.99) and check transaction counts.
2. register three **Non-consumable** items (limited jewel 1/2/3) and provide the next purchasable item for each purchase.

or, either looks fine?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the user can do with those jewels. If an item can be used once and then it is gone, it is a consumable. If it can be reused over and over, it is a non-consumable.

> **Consumable**
>
> Users can purchase different types of consumables, such as lives or gems in a game, to further their progress through an app. Consumable in-app purchases are used once, are depleted, and can be purchased again.
>
> **Non-Consumable**
>
> Users can purchase non-consumable, premium features within an app. Non-consumables are purchased once and do not expire, such as additional filters in a photo app.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use the "Consumable" type IAP, it complies with Apple Guideline because it will buy many times. The Non-consumable just use for one time.

After it reaches the third time, you can hide this feature, or prevent the user continue buying.